# Jmeter - While controller executes "if ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode() == "200" && counter < "5" not working

Tags: while-loop, jmeter

I want to control my sampler based on **responseCode** and needs to run n number of time defined in counter.
I used while controller and used condition as described below but it's not working as expected.
my condition in jmeter while controller :

```
${((${ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode()} == "200" && ${counter} < 5),)}
```

But it's not working as expected, could you please someone please help me on this.

Comment: Response code is an int, try == 200 (without double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

response code is an int try to use

(${ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode() == 200} && ${counter} < 5)

that is without the double quotes

Comment: Thanks for answering @gtosto,I changed it and try to execute it, the response I am getting is 400, but still the while loop executing without any stops, it should stop because it should execute only if response code is 200.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is malformed, you need to use i.e. [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function which evaluation result returns `true`. It can also be a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) having value of `true` which can be set to `false` somewhere else. But your expression is interpreted "as is" and not being evaluated.

Suggested amendment:

```
${__groovy(!ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode().equals('200') && (vars.get('counter') as int) < 5,)}
```

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/)